# Script en bash para abrir una URL y logearse en ella

Tags: bash, script, shell, shell-script

Quiero hacer un script que automatice una funcion (abrir clases a la universidad a distancia), y la primera vez que accedes te pide login. He intentado hacer algo asi:

```
curl --user usuario:contraseña URL
```

xdg-open URL de la clase en concreto

Sin embargo, al abrir la url me sigue pidiendo login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trata de volver a loggearte desde tu explorador y capturar la petición usando la función de modo desarrollador de tu explorador y seleccionando la pestaña "Network". Al momento de dar click en enviar, revisa las peticiones, da click derecho y selecciona la opción "Copy as cURL".

Con eso copiado (suponiendo que no tiene otro mecanismo de seguridad) podrías automatizar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]